# Subtract days from a date ignoring weekend days

Tags: mysql, sql, date, datetime, subquery

I'm trying to do a subtract operation on some dates, on my particular case I need to subtract only business days (excluding the weekends days, i.e, Sunday and Saturday)

my table looks like this:

```
date         | days_to_subtract   | dayName
23-04-2004   |   3                | Friday
23-05-2004   |   5                | Monday
21-04-2004   |   7                | Tuesday
25-04-2004   |   30               | Monday
01-04-2004   |   22               | Thursday
```

My goal consist on calculate a new column (new date) by subtracting **days_to_sub** from **date** taking into account only business (laboral) days and excluding (or ignoring) the weekends days.

I have tried something like this:

```
SELECT 
    CASE WHEN dayName = "Monday" then date_sub(date, days_to_subtract + 2)
         WHEN dayName = "Tuesday" then date_sub(date, days_to_subtract + 1)
         ELSE date_sub(date, days_to_subtract)
    END AS newColumn
FROM
    "MyTable"
```

But this will not work when the number of subtract days is greater than 5.

Any suggestion using simple SQL and no complicated functions to approach a solution to this problem?

Comment: Please tag your question with the database you are using.  What do you mean by "complicated FUNCTIONS"?

Comment: I'm using Mysql, I mean not T-sql

Comment: Store dates as dates. Then get back to us.

Comment: What do you want done with Holidays?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lets start with an explanation of your situation:

**Monday)** Suposse we are positioned on Monday, then the result you expect to (real) subtract when substracting N (virtual) days will be like:

```
"Mon" - 1 day  => "Mon" - (1 + 2 * (1)) days => "Mon" - 3 days  /* 1 weekend affecting */
"Mon" - 2 days => "Mon" - (2 + 2 * (1)) days => "Mon" - 4 days  /* 1 weekend affecting */
"Mon" - 3 days => "Mon" - (3 + 2 * (1)) days => "Mon" - 5 days  /* 1 weekend affecting */
...
"Mon" - 6 days => "Mon" - (6 + 2 * (2)) days => "Mon" - 10 days /* 2 weekends affecting */
...
```

**Tuesday)** Suposse we are positioned on Tuesday, then the result you expect to (real) subtract when substracting N (virtual) days will be like:

```
"Tue" - 1 day  => "Tue" - (1 + 2 * (0)) days => "Tue" - 1 days  /* 0 weekends affecting */
"Tue" - 2 days => "Tue" - (2 + 2 * (1)) days => "Tue" - 4 days  /* 1 weekend affecting */
"Tue" - 3 days => "Tue" - (3 + 2 * (1)) days => "Tue" - 5 days  /* 1 weekend affecting */
...
"Tue" - 6 days => "Tue" - (6 + 2 * (1)) days => "Tue" - 8 days  /* 1 weekend affecting */
"Tue" - 7 days => "Tue" - (7 + 2 * (2)) days => "Tue" - 11 days /* 2 weekends affecting */
...
```

**Wednesday)** Suposse we are positioned on Wednesday, then the result you expect to (real) subtract when substracting N (virtual) days will be like:

```
"Wed" - 1 day  => "Wed" - (1 + 2 * (0)) days => "Wed" - 1 days  /* 0 weekends affecting */
"Wed" - 2 days => "Wed" - (2 + 2 * (0)) days => "Wed" - 2 days  /* 0 weekends affecting */
"Wed" - 3 days => "Wed" - (3 + 2 * (1)) days => "Wed" - 5 days  /* 1 weekend affecting */
...
"Wed" - 6 days => "Wed" - (6 + 2 * (1)) days => "Wed" - 7 days  /* 1 weekend affecting */
"Wed" - 7 days => "Wed" - (7 + 2 * (1)) days => "Wed" - 9 days  /* 1 weekend affecting */
"Wed" - 8 days => "Wed" - (8 + 2 * (2)) days => "Wed" - 12 days /* 2 weekends affecting */
...
```

As we can note, there is a mathematical calculus in the middle of this logic. If we indexes the days of the week in this way:

```
0 <-> Monday
1 <-> Tuesday
2 <-> Wednesday
3 <-> Thursday
4 <-> Friday
```

Then, a formula that match the previous calculus would be:

```
Week_Day - X days => Week_Day - X days + 2 * CEIL((X - INDEX_OF(Week_Day)) / 5) days

where INDEX_OF() is a function that returns the previous indexing for days.
```

**Example 1)**

Suppose we need to subtract 2 days from Wednesday, then the previous formula will reduce to this:

```
"Wed" - 2 days => "Wed" - 2 + 2 * CEIL((2 - 2) / 5)
"Wed" - 2 days => "Wed" - 2 + 2 * CEIL(0 / 5)
"Wed" - 2 days => "Wed" - 2 + 2 * 0
"Wed" - 2 days => "Wed" - 2 + 0
"Wed" - 2 days => "Wed" - 2 days
```

**Example 2)**

Suppose we need to subtract 8 days from Wednesday (in this case we have two weekends in the middle of the subtract) then the previous formula will reduce to this:

```
"Wed" - 8 days => "Wed" - 8 + 2 * CEIL((8 - 2) / 5)
"Wed" - 8 days => "Wed" - 8 + 2 * CEIL(6 / 5)
"Wed" - 8 days => "Wed" - 8 + 2 * 2 /* Two weekends are affecting */
"Wed" - 8 days => "Wed" - 8 + 4
"Wed" - 8 days => "Wed" - 12 days
```

So, based on this formula and manipulating the MySQL **DAYOFWEEK()** method for generate our **INDEX_OF()** function, we can do the next query:

```
SELECT
    date AS OriginalDate,
    DAYOFWEEK(date) - 2 AS IndexOfDay,
    days_to_subtract AS DaysToSubtract,
    2 * CEIL((days_to_subtract - (DAYOFWEEK(date) - 2)) / 5) AS WeekendDaysToAdd,
    DATE_SUB(
        date,
        INTERVAL days_to_subtract + (2 * CEIL((days_to_subtract -  (DAYOFWEEK(date) - 2)) / 5)) DAY
    ) AS CalucaltedDay
FROM
    myTable
```

The last column **CalculatedDay** will contain the date you expect to obtain from the subtract, the others columns are just for check the steps of the mathematical calculus. I hope you can understand the logic behind this, because it costme some time to figure it out and try to explain it. You can see working examples on next links:

**1)** [DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/poPTwZukmDc8rp7yiWfqMR/0)

**2)** [SQL Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/7c8f45/2)

Comment: It's working perfectly ! Great solution thanks a lot for the explanations

Comment: You are welcome, I have made some changes on the explanation, in case this can help other people. Good to know it helps you.